# How to update the style of an element within an element using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the javascript below, how would I designate the class btn that exists within the div id = 8?
Also, if I needed to add "!important" to the background color, how would I do that?

```js
$('#8 .btn')[0].style.background = 'white';
```

```css
body{
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="8">
<div class="1">
<div class="2">
<div></div>
<a class="btn">...</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify the issue you're having? Your code works but it's jquery so you need to make sure you're importing that to use that script. https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/mhpueyx3/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will probably help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: red;">
   <div id="8">
    <div class="1">
     <div class="2">
      <div></div>
      <a class="btn">example ban</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    
     const collection = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
     collection[0].style.setProperty("background", "white", "important")
   
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned, there will be more than one class of "btn" on the page, I specifically am trying to pinpoint the one that exists within the div with id = 8.

Comment: oh in that case you can do the following: document.getElementById("8").getElementsByClassName("btn"). In you example you only have one element with class 'btn'. the methods getElementsByClassName always will return you an array of elements you probably have to interact that array though.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.